# Wifi card hard locked after suspend or hibernate

Tags: wifi, power-management, suspend, pop-os, iwlwifi

Every time my pc suspends or hibernate the wifi card hard lock is enabled and there is no way to disable it. I run Pop OS on an MSI GS 65. Fn + f10 (airplane mode) doesn't work.

I have tried changing /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf from `default.powersave=3` to `default.powersave=2` and restarting the service, but without any luck.

Output from rfkill list:

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Output from dmesg:

```
[   97.113717] ACPI: EC: EC started
[   97.113718] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[   97.116706] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[   97.116749] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[   97.116750] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[   97.119566] CPU1 is up
[   97.119586] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[   97.121359] CPU2 is up
[   97.121378] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[   97.123142] CPU3 is up
[   97.123160] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x8
[   97.124945] CPU4 is up
[   97.124963] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0xa
[   97.126843] CPU5 is up
[   97.126862] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x1
[   97.127665] CPU6 is up
[   97.127688] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x3
[   97.128351] CPU7 is up
[   97.128370] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 8 APIC 0x5
[   97.129037] CPU8 is up
[   97.129056] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 9 APIC 0x7
[   97.129740] CPU9 is up
[   97.129758] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 10 APIC 0x9
[   97.130460] CPU10 is up
[   97.130479] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 11 APIC 0xb
[   97.131215] CPU11 is up
[   97.135447] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[   97.140888] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[   98.284597] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[   98.287487] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[   98.316437] nvme nvme1: 7/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[   98.319561] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 10 seconds
[   98.320927] nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[   98.555173] usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   99.012108] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5666], y [..4688]
[   99.043031] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1274..], y [1166..]
[  101.228949] acpi LNXPOWER:05: Turning OFF
[  101.229007] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
[  101.229111] OOM killer enabled.
[  101.229114] Restarting tasks ...
[  101.229300] usb 1-11: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  101.232779] done.
[  101.234198] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[  101.234878] thermal thermal_zone2: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[  101.362832] PM: suspend exit
[  101.847443] usb 1-14: USB disconnect, device number 5
```